# Node cron job executes only first time on GCP App Engine

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cron

I have a problem executing a cron job in node/express application using node-cron library. The application is deployed on Google Cloud App Engine.

I want to send automatic emails every day at 9 AM, but the cron only work in the first day and then never sends.

Here is my code :

```
 cron.schedule("0 0 9 * * *", () => {
  sendEmails();
 },{
    scheduled: true,
    timezone: "Europe/Paris"
  });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here you have 2 issues. A cron expression have only 5 elements not 6.

Also according to your expression your cron will be excecuted on the dat 9 of each month

[image]

probably you want something like this

[image]

You probably want to verify your cron expression with a tool like https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Hi @Chris32 I changet it, so the cron exexuted Thursday, Friday and it stopped Saturday and Suanday and it worked today. So in the weekend it didn't work.

Comment: To run a job only on weekdays you need to enter something similar to "0 9 * * 1-5" unless you are entering something similar to this your job is not running by another cause. I recommend you look into your Cloud Logs to determine if in fact, your job is not running at all or if maybe the action is not being executed as expected. If you determine that your job is not running at all I suggest you open a ticket with [Google Cloud Billing support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) to investigate this issue in more detail